# Script that only counts Established, TIME_WAIT, and Closed Wait connections using Netstat

Tags: linux, awk, scripting, perl, ksh

I'm trying to make a script (using Perl, but it isn't necessary) that will only count the number of Established, Time_Wait, and Closed_Wait connections on a system and print them in terminal. So far I've figured out that I can use :

```
netstat -ant | awk '{print $6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

in order to print all of the connections, but when I run this from a script it will not print in terminal and it also gives me some connections that I am not looking for such as Listen and Foreign. The reason why it must only show Established, Time_Wait, and Closed_Wait is because the script is being used by a monitoring program that will fail if any other connection types show up. Can anyone make a suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: my %count;
open my $NET, '-|', qw{ /bin/netstat -ant } or die $!;
<$NET> ; <$NET> ;#Removes "Foreign"
while (<$NET>) {
    my ($protocol, $recv, $send, $local_addr, $foreign_addr, $state) = split;

    # Do whatever you need with the information, e.g.
    $count{$state}++;
}
for my $state (keys %count) {
    print "$state\t$count{$state}\n";
}

Comment: netstat -nat | egrep 'ESTABLISHED|TIME_WAIT|CLOSE_WAIT' | wc -l

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script can be slightly modified to only process the states you need:

```
netstat -ant | awk '/ESTABLISHED|LISTEN|CLOSE_WAIT/ {print $6}' | \
    sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

A further step would be to everything with `awk`, e.g. :

```
netstat -ant | awk '
/ESTABLISHED|LISTEN|CLOSE_WAIT/ {count[$6]++}
END {
  for(s in count) {
    printf("%12s : %6d\n", s, count[s]);
  }
}'
```

Comment: This was fantastic, thank you! Is there any way you could also help develop the rest of the script so that when the program is run it only outputs those three lines?

Comment: It's hard to tell without more information about what the rest of the script should be.

Comment: The output that you originally gave to me was perfect, I am just having trouble making the rest of the script that the monitoring program will execute on it's own to get that exact same output every time, just with updated connection counts.

Comment: I really just need the script to ignore anything else that could pop up such as FIN_WAIT2, I'm only looking for established, time wait, and close wait.

Comment: What script are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Count the lines:

```
netstat -nat | egrep 'ESTABLISHED|TIME_WAIT|CLOSE_WAIT' | wc -l
```

Print only those lines:

```
netstat -nat | egrep 'ESTABLISHED|TIME_WAIT|CLOSE_WAIT'
```